# Does weak convergence transfer to order statistics?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, weak-convergence, order-statistics, skorohod-space

let's say $\underline{X}_n=(X^1_n,\ldots,X^k_n)$ is a series of random vectors, each consisting of $k$ i.i.d. entries, which converges in distribution to $\underline{X}$ as $n$ grows to infinity. We could analyse these vectors as samples of length $k$.

Clearly, a la Skorokhod, the first order statistic $X^{[1]}_n\xrightarrow{d}X^{[1]}$ then also converges in distribution, since taking the maximum of a vector is a continuous operation from $\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$. Compare $\max(v_1,v_2)=(v_1+v_2+|v_1-v_2|)/2$. The same could be said about the $k$-th order statistic, aka the minimum. But what about all the order statistics in between, can we say anything about their convergence?

I'm aware of what makes these two especially easy: for the maximum to be $\leq x$ is the same event as having all entries be $\leq x$.  Meanwhile for the order statistics in between you'd have to do some combinatorics. But still, I couldn't find anything on this and would be thankful for all help :)

Comment: If $X_n \Rightarrow X$, then $(X_n^1,X_n^2)\Rightarrow (X_1,X_2)$ and the claim follows

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks. I think I understand why it works for k=2, but what about bigger $k$? By order statistics I mean the entries of $X_n$ but rearranged after drawing in such a way that $X^{[1]}_n\leq X^{[2]}_n\leq\ldots\leq X^{[k]}_n$

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I completely botched my comment. Anyhow, for $k=3$, if you are interested in $X_n^{(2)}$, then I believe this should be $X_n^{(2)} = \min\{\max(X_n^1,X_n^2),\max(X_n^1,X_n^3),\max(X_n^2,X_n^3)\}$, which converges weakly to $X^{(2)}$ by continuous mapping theorem. Not very elegant, but I think this argument should generalize.

Comment: Ohhh that's good, I can already see how to generalize this. Alternatively I would have maybe shown from first principles how finding $X^{(j)}$ is continuous and done an $\epsilon-\delta$ thing .. if another entry wants to displace the current top dog for j-th place it first has to sneak up to it, lol. but that would be even more messy than your solution.
Most importantly, I'm convinced now that the claim is true.